# How to pass python lambda func to c++ std::function<> using Boost.Python

Tags: python, c++, lambda, boost, interface

Just lets consider next example:

```cpp
#include <functional>

class Model
{
  function<bool(const vector<double>&, float, float, float)> q_bifurcate_pointer;
}
```

Now in c++ env I can simply assign lambda value to `q_bifurcate_pointer`:

```cpp
model.q_bifurcate_pointer = [](const vector<double>& a, float branch_lenght, float bifurcation_threshold, float bifurcation_min_dist)->bool
            {
                return (a.at(2) / a.at(0) <= bifurcation_threshold) 
                    && branch_lenght >= bifurcation_min_dist;
            };
```

Next I try to export that class to python using 'Boost.Python':

```cpp
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(riversim)
{
class_<vector<double>> ("t_v_double")
  .def(vector_indexing_suite<vector<double>>());

class_<Model>("Model")
  .def_readwrite("q_bifurcate_pointer", &Model::q_bifurcate_pointer)
}
```

And now we are getting finally to the problem. In python I can execute next lines:

```py
import riversim
model = riversim.Model()
model.q_bifurcate_pointer = lambda a, b, c, d: True

# or more complicated example with type specification
from typing import Callable

func: Callable[[riversim.t_v_double, float, float, float], bool] = lambda a, b, c, d: True
model.q_bifurcate_pointer = func
```

And in both cases I am getting next error:

```sh
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ArgumentError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/oleg/Documents/riversim/riversimpy/histogram.ipynb Cell 2' in <module>
      3 model = riversim.Model()
      4 func: Callable[[riversim.t_v_double, float, float, float], bool] = lambda a, b, c, d: True
----> 5 model.q_bifurcate_pointer = func

ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    None.None(Model, function)
did not match C++ signature:
    None(River::Model {lvalue}, std::function<bool (std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&, float, float, float)>)
```

So, how to create proper lambda function and past it to my c++ code?

Comment: You probably want to accept a python function object, which you then adequately wrap on the C++ to invoke it using Boost Python mechanisms. You then assign the wrapped function to the q_bifurcate_pointer callback. I have little experience with the advanced typemapping/reverse calling (essentially python embedding) interface of Boost Python, so I cannot easily code it up as an example.

Comment: @sehe probably I was to naive, to think that this is possible. Lambda expression in pythone - this is byte code and C++ needs machine code. Just googled similar to mine but more general problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437932/how-to-pass-python-function-as-an-argument-to-c-function-using-cython

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda expression in pythone - this is byte code and C++ needs machine code. Just googled similar to mine but more general problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30445958/4437603